# Draw points line from bar to bar in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I want create line connect after bar with next before bar like as  image under
[image]

Comment: did you checkout the official examples like this one https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/combo-bar-line.html

Comment: There is no simple solution to achieve what you want. You may try using the [`chartjs-plugin-annotation`](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/). But to get a solution here on stackoverflow, you should post your code (see how to write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and what you have attempted to do. From the image attached it's unclear how your data is structured and where exactly do you want those lines drawn.

Comment: @winner_joiner Sorry use it but is not correct my issue , Can you help me? https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-css-javascript-basic-zbsntn?file=index.js

Comment: Your demo seems to look like your image. I'm sorry don't really understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom chartjs plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) to create the line connector, then draw the line on [beforeDatasetsDraw](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/Plugin.html#beforedatasetsdraw) callback using canvas provided by chartjs,

use `bar._model.y` to get the top position of each bar

use `bar._model.base` to get the bottom position of each bar

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'A',
          data: [[12,14], [14,24],[10,12]],
        borderWidth: 1
        },
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}



const barConnector = {
  id: 'barConnector',
  beforeDatasetsDraw: function(chart, args, plugins){
    const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
    ctx.save();
    const datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;

    datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {
      dataset.data.forEach((data, dataIndex) => {
        if(dataIndex === dataset.data.length - 1) return;
        const bar = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data[dataIndex];
        const barX = bar._model.x;
        const barY = bar._model.y;

        const nextBar = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data[dataIndex + 1];
        const nextBarX = nextBar?._model.x;
        const nextBarY = nextBar?._model.base;
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(barX+46, barY);
        ctx.lineTo(nextBarX-46, nextBarY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.backgroundColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.stroke();
      })
    });
  }
}

options.plugins = [barConnector]

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-js').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart-js" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```